# Internal Server Error on phpmyadmin Log in

Tags: phpmyadmin

I have installed phpmyadmin successfully from [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-install-and-secure-phpmyadmin-on-ubuntu-12-04).

I could do LogIn into that without any problems before restarting machine.

After restarting machine, when i'm going to `localhost/phpmyadmin` and enter the user(`root`) and its password(`123456`), it get me :

`500 Internal Server Error`

I have no idea what't wrong with that!

Any help would be appreciated.

**EDIT :** {Add more informations}

`var/log/Apache2/error.log`

```
[Sun Jul 28 11:41:50 2013] [notice] Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu) PHP/5.3.10-1ubuntu3.7 with Suhosin-Patch configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sun Jul 28 12:53:22 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] (2)No such file or directory: Could not open password file: /path/to/passwords/.htpasswd
[Sun Jul 28 12:53:22 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] File does not exist: /home/hamed/public_html/favicon.ico
[Sun Jul 28 12:53:26 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] (2)No such file or directory: Could not open password file: /path/to/passwords/.htpasswd
[Sun Jul 28 12:53:26 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] File does not exist: /home/hamed/public_html/favicon.ico
[Sun Jul 28 12:53:32 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] (2)No such file or directory: Could not open password file: /path/to/passwords/.htpasswd
[Sun Jul 28 12:53:32 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] File does not exist: /home/hamed/public_html/favicon.ico
[Sun Jul 28 12:53:38 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] (2)No such file or directory: Could not open password file: /path/to/passwords/.htpasswd
[Sun Jul 28 12:53:38 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] File does not exist: /home/hamed/public_html/favicon.ico
Failed loading /usr/lib/php5/20090626+lfs/xdebug.so:  /usr/lib/php5/20090626+lfs/xdebug.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Failed loading /usr/lib/php5/20090626+lfs/xdebug.so:  /usr/lib/php5/20090626+lfs/xdebug.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
[Sun Jul 28 12:54:10 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] (2)No such file or directory: Could not open password file: /path/to/passwords/.htpasswd
[Sun Jul 28 12:54:10 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] File does not exist: /home/hamed/public_html/favicon.ico
[Sun Jul 28 12:54:10 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] File does not exist: /home/hamed/public_html/favicon.ico
[Sun Jul 28 12:54:52 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] (2)No such file or directory: Could not open password file: /path/to/passwords/.htpasswd
[Sun Jul 28 12:54:52 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] File does not exist: /home/hamed/public_html/favicon.ico
[Sun Jul 28 12:55:34 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] (2)No such file or directory: Could not open password file: /path/to/passwords/.htpasswd
[Sun Jul 28 12:55:34 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] File does not exist: /home/hamed/public_html/favicon.ico
[Sun Jul 28 12:55:34 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] File does not exist: /home/hamed/public_html/favicon.ico
[Sun Jul 28 12:56:00 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] (2)No such file or directory: Could not open password file: /path/to/passwords/.htpasswd
[Sun Jul 28 12:56:12 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] (2)No such file or directory: Could not open password file: /path/to/passwords/.htpasswd
[Sun Jul 28 12:56:17 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] (2)No such file or directory: Could not open password file: /path/to/passwords/.htpasswd
[Sun Jul 28 13:54:49 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] File does not exist: /home/hamed/public_html/favicon.ico, referer: http://localhost/PHP_SelectQuery/index.php
[Sun Jul 28 14:06:19 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: healthy in /home/hamed/public_html/PHP_SelectQuery/index.php on line 2
[Sun Jul 28 14:06:24 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Warning:  mysql_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /home/hamed/public_html/PHP_SelectQuery/index.php on line 14, referer: http://localhost/PHP_SelectQuery/index.php
[Sun Jul 28 14:06:45 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: healthy in /home/hamed/public_html/PHP_SelectQuery/index.php on line 2
[Sun Jul 28 14:06:46 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: food in /home/hamed/public_html/PHP_SelectQuery/index.php on line 15, referer: http://localhost/PHP_SelectQuery/index.php
[Sun Jul 28 14:06:46 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: food in /home/hamed/public_html/PHP_SelectQuery/index.php on line 15, referer: http://localhost/PHP_SelectQuery/index.php
[Sun Jul 28 14:06:46 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: food in /home/hamed/public_html/PHP_SelectQuery/index.php on line 15, referer: http://localhost/PHP_SelectQuery/index.php
[Sun Jul 28 14:06:46 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: food in /home/hamed/public_html/PHP_SelectQuery/index.php on line 15, referer: http://localhost/PHP_SelectQuery/index.php
[Sun Jul 28 14:06:52 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Warning:  mysql_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /home/hamed/public_html/PHP_SelectQuery/index.php on line 14, referer: http://localhost/PHP_SelectQuery/index.php?healthy=healthy
[Sun Jul 28 14:06:54 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: food in /home/hamed/public_html/PHP_SelectQuery/index.php on line 15, referer: http://localhost/PHP_SelectQuery/index.php?healthy=unhealthy
[Sun Jul 28 14:06:54 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: food in /home/hamed/public_html/PHP_SelectQuery/index.php on line 15, referer: http://localhost/PHP_SelectQuery/index.php?healthy=unhealthy
[Sun Jul 28 14:06:54 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: food in /home/hamed/public_html/PHP_SelectQuery/index.php on line 15, referer: http://localhost/PHP_SelectQuery/index.php?healthy=unhealthy
[Sun Jul 28 14:06:54 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: food in /home/hamed/public_html/PHP_SelectQuery/index.php on line 15, referer: http://localhost/PHP_SelectQuery/index.php?healthy=unhealthy
[Sun Jul 28 14:07:53 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: healthy in /home/hamed/public_html/PHP_SelectQuery/index.php on line 2
[Sun Jul 28 14:07:54 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: food in /home/hamed/public_html/PHP_SelectQuery/index.php on line 15, referer: http://localhost/PHP_SelectQuery/index.php
[Sun Jul 28 14:07:54 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: food in /home/hamed/public_html/PHP_SelectQuery/index.php on line 15, referer: http://localhost/PHP_SelectQuery/index.php
[Sun Jul 28 14:07:54 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: food in /home/hamed/public_html/PHP_SelectQuery/index.php on line 15, referer: http://localhost/PHP_SelectQuery/index.php
[Sun Jul 28 14:07:54 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: food in /home/hamed/public_html/PHP_SelectQuery/index.php on line 15, referer: http://localhost/PHP_SelectQuery/index.php
[Sun Jul 28 14:08:23 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: food in /home/hamed/public_html/PHP_SelectQuery/index.php on line 15, referer: http://localhost/PHP_SelectQuery/index.php
[Sun Jul 28 14:08:23 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: food in /home/hamed/public_html/PHP_SelectQuery/index.php on line 15, referer: http://localhost/PHP_SelectQuery/index.php
[Sun Jul 28 14:08:23 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: food in /home/hamed/public_html/PHP_SelectQuery/index.php on line 15, referer: http://localhost/PHP_SelectQuery/index.php
[Sun Jul 28 14:08:23 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: food in /home/hamed/public_html/PHP_SelectQuery/index.php on line 15, referer: http://localhost/PHP_SelectQuery/index.php
[Sun Jul 28 14:08:32 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: healthy in /home/hamed/public_html/PHP_SelectQuery/index.php on line 2
[Sun Jul 28 14:08:33 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: food in /home/hamed/public_html/PHP_SelectQuery/index.php on line 15, referer: http://localhost/PHP_SelectQuery/index.php
[Sun Jul 28 14:08:33 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: food in /home/hamed/public_html/PHP_SelectQuery/index.php on line 15, referer: http://localhost/PHP_SelectQuery/index.php
[Sun Jul 28 14:08:33 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: food in /home/hamed/public_html/PHP_SelectQuery/index.php on line 15, referer: http://localhost/PHP_SelectQuery/index.php
[Sun Jul 28 14:08:33 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: food in /home/hamed/public_html/PHP_SelectQuery/index.php on line 15, referer: http://localhost/PHP_SelectQuery/index.php
[Sun Jul 28 14:09:39 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: healthy in /home/hamed/public_html/PHP_SelectQuery/index.php on line 2
[Sun Jul 28 14:09:41 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: food in /home/hamed/public_html/PHP_SelectQuery/index.php on line 16, referer: http://localhost/PHP_SelectQuery/index.php
[Sun Jul 28 14:09:41 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: food in /home/hamed/public_html/PHP_SelectQuery/index.php on line 16, referer: http://localhost/PHP_SelectQuery/index.php
[Sun Jul 28 14:09:41 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: food in /home/hamed/public_html/PHP_SelectQuery/index.php on line 16, referer: http://localhost/PHP_SelectQuery/index.php
[Sun Jul 28 14:09:41 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: food in /home/hamed/public_html/PHP_SelectQuery/index.php on line 16, referer: http://localhost/PHP_SelectQuery/index.php
[Sun Jul 28 14:09:44 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Warning:  mysql_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /home/hamed/public_html/PHP_SelectQuery/index.php on line 15, referer: http://localhost/PHP_SelectQuery/index.php?healthy=healthy
[Sun Jul 28 14:09:48 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: food in /home/hamed/public_html/PHP_SelectQuery/index.php on line 16, referer: http://localhost/PHP_SelectQuery/index.php?healthy=unhealthy
[Sun Jul 28 14:09:48 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: food in /home/hamed/public_html/PHP_SelectQuery/index.php on line 16, referer: http://localhost/PHP_SelectQuery/index.php?healthy=unhealthy
[Sun Jul 28 14:09:48 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: food in /home/hamed/public_html/PHP_SelectQuery/index.php on line 16, referer: http://localhost/PHP_SelectQuery/index.php?healthy=unhealthy
[Sun Jul 28 14:09:48 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: food in /home/hamed/public_html/PHP_SelectQuery/index.php on line 16, referer: http://localhost/PHP_SelectQuery/index.php?healthy=unhealthy
[Sun Jul 28 14:10:28 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: healthy in /home/hamed/public_html/PHP_SelectQuery/index.php on line 2
[Sun Jul 28 14:10:29 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: name in /home/hamed/public_html/PHP_SelectQuery/index.php on line 16, referer: http://localhost/PHP_SelectQuery/index.php
[Sun Jul 28 14:10:29 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: name in /home/hamed/public_html/PHP_SelectQuery/index.php on line 16, referer: http://localhost/PHP_SelectQuery/index.php
[Sun Jul 28 14:10:29 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: name in /home/hamed/public_html/PHP_SelectQuery/index.php on line 16, referer: http://localhost/PHP_SelectQuery/index.php
[Sun Jul 28 14:10:29 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: name in /home/hamed/public_html/PHP_SelectQuery/index.php on line 16, referer: http://localhost/PHP_SelectQuery/index.php
Failed loading /usr/lib/php5/20090626+lfs/xdebug.so:  /usr/lib/php5/20090626+lfs/xdebug.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Failed loading /usr/lib/php5/20090626+lfs/xdebug.so:  /usr/lib/php5/20090626+lfs/xdebug.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Failed loading /usr/lib/php5/20090626+lfs/xdebug.so:  /usr/lib/php5/20090626+lfs/xdebug.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Failed loading /usr/lib/php5/20090626+lfs/xdebug.so:  /usr/lib/php5/20090626+lfs/xdebug.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Failed loading /usr/lib/php5/20090626+lfs/xdebug.so:  /usr/lib/php5/20090626+lfs/xdebug.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Failed loading /usr/lib/php5/20090626+lfs/xdebug.so:  /usr/lib/php5/20090626+lfs/xdebug.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Failed loading /usr/lib/php5/20090626+lfs/xdebug.so:  /usr/lib/php5/20090626+lfs/xdebug.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Failed loading /usr/lib/php5/20090626+lfs/xdebug.so:  /usr/lib/php5/20090626+lfs/xdebug.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Failed loading /usr/lib/php5/20090626+lfs/xdebug.so:  /usr/lib/php5/20090626+lfs/xdebug.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Failed loading /usr/lib/php5/20090626+lfs/xdebug.so:  /usr/lib/php5/20090626+lfs/xdebug.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Failed loading /usr/lib/php5/20090626+lfs/xdebug.so:  /usr/lib/php5/20090626+lfs/xdebug.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Failed loading /usr/lib/php5/20090626+lfs/xdebug.so:  /usr/lib/php5/20090626+lfs/xdebug.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Failed loading /usr/lib/php5/20090626+lfs/xdebug.so:  /usr/lib/php5/20090626+lfs/xdebug.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Failed loading /usr/lib/php5/20090626+lfs/xdebug.so:  /usr/lib/php5/20090626+lfs/xdebug.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Failed loading /usr/lib/php5/20090626+lfs/xdebug.so:  /usr/lib/php5/20090626+lfs/xdebug.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Failed loading /usr/lib/php5/20090626+lfs/xdebug.so:  /usr/lib/php5/20090626+lfs/xdebug.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Failed loading /usr/lib/php5/20090626+lfs/xdebug.so:  /usr/lib/php5/20090626+lfs/xdebug.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Failed loading /usr/lib/php5/20090626+lfs/xdebug.so:  /usr/lib/php5/20090626+lfs/xdebug.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Failed loading /usr/lib/php5/20090626+lfs/xdebug.so:  /usr/lib/php5/20090626+lfs/xdebug.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Failed loading /usr/lib/php5/20090626+lfs/xdebug.so:  /usr/lib/php5/20090626+lfs/xdebug.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
[Sun Jul 28 14:33:35 2013] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down
Failed loading /usr/lib/php5/20090626+lfs/xdebug.so:  /usr/lib/php5/20090626+lfs/xdebug.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Failed loading /usr/lib/php5/20090626+lfs/xdebug.so:  /usr/lib/php5/20090626+lfs/xdebug.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
[Mon Jul 29 01:09:32 2013] [notice] Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu) PHP/5.3.10-1ubuntu3.7 with Suhosin-Patch configured -- resuming normal operations
Failed loading /usr/lib/php5/20090626+lfs/xdebug.so:  /usr/lib/php5/20090626+lfs/xdebug.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Failed loading /usr/lib/php5/20090626+lfs/xdebug.so:  /usr/lib/php5/20090626+lfs/xdebug.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Failed loading /usr/lib/php5/20090626+lfs/xdebug.so:  /usr/lib/php5/20090626+lfs/xdebug.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Failed loading /usr/lib/php5/20090626+lfs/xdebug.so:  /usr/lib/php5/20090626+lfs/xdebug.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Failed loading /usr/lib/php5/20090626+lfs/xdebug.so:  /usr/lib/php5/20090626+lfs/xdebug.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
[Mon Jul 29 01:27:40 2013] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down
Failed loading /usr/lib/php5/20090626+lfs/xdebug.so:  /usr/lib/php5/20090626+lfs/xdebug.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
[Mon Jul 29 10:22:19 2013] [notice] Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu) PHP/5.3.10-1ubuntu3.7 with Suhosin-Patch configured -- resuming normal operations
[Mon Jul 29 10:49:19 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] (2)No such file or directory: Could not open password file: /path/to/passwords/.htpasswd
[Mon Jul 29 10:49:19 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] File does not exist: /home/hamed/public_html/favicon.ico
[Mon Jul 29 10:55:21 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] (2)No such file or directory: Could not open password file: /path/to/passwords/.htpasswd
[Mon Jul 29 10:55:21 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] File does not exist: /home/hamed/public_html/favicon.ico
[Mon Jul 29 11:02:41 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] (2)No such file or directory: Could not open password file: /path/to/passwords/.htpasswd
[Mon Jul 29 11:02:42 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] File does not exist: /home/hamed/public_html/favicon.ico
[Mon Jul 29 11:02:42 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] File does not exist: /home/hamed/public_html/favicon.ico
[Mon Jul 29 11:21:41 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] (2)No such file or directory: Could not open password file: /path/to/passwords/.htpasswd
[Mon Jul 29 11:21:42 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] File does not exist: /home/hamed/public_html/favicon.ico
[Mon Jul 29 11:21:42 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] File does not exist: /home/hamed/public_html/favicon.ico
[Mon Jul 29 11:22:58 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] (2)No such file or directory: Could not open password file: /path/to/passwords/.htpasswd
[Mon Jul 29 11:22:58 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] File does not exist: /home/hamed/public_html/favicon.ico
[Mon Jul 29 11:22:58 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] File does not exist: /home/hamed/public_html/favicon.ico
[Mon Jul 29 12:01:08 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: healthy in /home/hamed/public_html/PHP_SelectQuery/index.php on line 2
[Mon Jul 29 12:01:08 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] File does not exist: /home/hamed/public_html/favicon.ico, referer: http://localhost/PHP_SelectQuery/index.php
[Mon Jul 29 12:01:12 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: name in /home/hamed/public_html/PHP_SelectQuery/index.php on line 16, referer: http://localhost/PHP_SelectQuery/index.php
[Mon Jul 29 12:01:12 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: name in /home/hamed/public_html/PHP_SelectQuery/index.php on line 16, referer: http://localhost/PHP_SelectQuery/index.php
[Mon Jul 29 12:01:12 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: name in /home/hamed/public_html/PHP_SelectQuery/index.php on line 16, referer: http://localhost/PHP_SelectQuery/index.php
[Mon Jul 29 12:01:12 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: name in /home/hamed/public_html/PHP_SelectQuery/index.php on line 16, referer: http://localhost/PHP_SelectQuery/index.php
[Mon Jul 29 12:01:15 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Warning:  mysql_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /home/hamed/public_html/PHP_SelectQuery/index.php on line 15, referer: http://localhost/PHP_SelectQuery/index.php?healthy=healthy
[Mon Jul 29 12:02:37 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: healthy in /home/hamed/public_html/PHP_SelectQuery/index.php on line 2
[Mon Jul 29 12:02:38 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Warning:  mysql_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /home/hamed/public_html/PHP_SelectQuery/index.php on line 15, referer: http://localhost/PHP_SelectQuery/index.php
[Mon Jul 29 12:06:01 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: healthy in /home/hamed/public_html/PHP_SelectQuery/index.php on line 2
[Mon Jul 29 12:06:02 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: name in /home/hamed/public_html/PHP_SelectQuery/index.php on line 16, referer: http://localhost/PHP_SelectQuery/index.php
[Mon Jul 29 12:06:02 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: name in /home/hamed/public_html/PHP_SelectQuery/index.php on line 16, referer: http://localhost/PHP_SelectQuery/index.php
[Mon Jul 29 12:06:04 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: name in /home/hamed/public_html/PHP_SelectQuery/index.php on line 16, referer: http://localhost/PHP_SelectQuery/index.php?healthy=healthy
[Mon Jul 29 12:06:04 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: name in /home/hamed/public_html/PHP_SelectQuery/index.php on line 16, referer: http://localhost/PHP_SelectQuery/index.php?healthy=healthy
[Mon Jul 29 12:06:07 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: name in /home/hamed/public_html/PHP_SelectQuery/index.php on line 16, referer: http://localhost/PHP_SelectQuery/index.php?healthy=unhealthy
[Mon Jul 29 12:06:07 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: name in /home/hamed/public_html/PHP_SelectQuery/index.php on line 16, referer: http://localhost/PHP_SelectQuery/index.php?healthy=unhealthy
[Mon Jul 29 12:06:09 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: name in /home/hamed/public_html/PHP_SelectQuery/index.php on line 16, referer: http://localhost/PHP_SelectQuery/index.php?healthy=healthy
[Mon Jul 29 12:06:09 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: name in /home/hamed/public_html/PHP_SelectQuery/index.php on line 16, referer: http://localhost/PHP_SelectQuery/index.php?healthy=healthy
[Mon Jul 29 12:06:38 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: healthy in /home/hamed/public_html/PHP_SelectQuery/index.php on line 2
[Mon Jul 29 12:07:23 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: healthy in /home/hamed/public_html/PHP_SelectQuery/index.php on line 2
[Mon Jul 29 12:08:20 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: healthy in /home/hamed/public_html/PHP_SelectQuery/index.php on line 2
[Mon Jul 29 12:08:32 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: healthy in /home/hamed/public_html/PHP_SelectQuery/index.php on line 2
[Mon Jul 29 12:09:12 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: healthy in /home/hamed/public_html/PHP_SelectQuery/index.php on line 2
[Mon Jul 29 12:09:35 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: healthy in /home/hamed/public_html/PHP_SelectQuery/index.php on line 2
[Mon Jul 29 12:12:47 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] File does not exist: /home/hamed/public_html/phpMyAdmin, referer: http://superuser.com/questions/114221/how-can-i-start-phpmyadmin/114258
[Mon Jul 29 12:12:47 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] File does not exist: /home/hamed/public_html/favicon.ico
[Mon Jul 29 12:12:53 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] File does not exist: /home/hamed/public_html/phpMyAdmin
[Mon Jul 29 12:12:53 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] File does not exist: /home/hamed/public_html/favicon.ico
[Mon Jul 29 12:12:57 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] File does not exist: /home/hamed/public_html/phpMyAdmin
[Mon Jul 29 12:12:57 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] File does not exist: /home/hamed/public_html/favicon.ico
[Mon Jul 29 12:13:06 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] File does not exist: /home/hamed/public_html/phpMyAdmin
[Mon Jul 29 12:13:06 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] File does not exist: /home/hamed/public_html/favicon.ico
[Mon Jul 29 12:13:06 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] File does not exist: /home/hamed/public_html/favicon.ico
[Mon Jul 29 12:14:48 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: healthy in /home/hamed/public_html/PHP_SelectQuery/index.php on line 2
[Mon Jul 29 12:15:20 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: healthy in /home/hamed/public_html/PHP_SelectQuery/index.php on line 2
[Mon Jul 29 12:15:37 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: healthy in /home/hamed/public_html/PHP_SelectQuery/index.php on line 2
[Mon Jul 29 12:15:55 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: healthy in /home/hamed/public_html/PHP_SelectQuery/index.php on line 2
[Mon Jul 29 12:16:21 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: healthy in /home/hamed/public_html/PHP_SelectQuery/index.php on line 2
[Mon Jul 29 12:16:38 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: healthy in /home/hamed/public_html/PHP_SelectQuery/index.php on line 2
[Mon Jul 29 12:52:10 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: healthy in /home/hamed/public_html/PHP_SelectQuery/index.php on line 3
[Mon Jul 29 12:52:22 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: healthy in /home/hamed/public_html/PHP_SelectQuery/index.php on line 3
[Mon Jul 29 12:53:14 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: healthy in /home/hamed/public_html/PHP_SelectQuery/index.php on line 3
[Mon Jul 29 12:54:01 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: healthy in /home/hamed/public_html/PHP_SelectQuery/index.php on line 3
Failed loading /usr/lib/php5/20090626+lfs/xdebug.so:  /usr/lib/php5/20090626+lfs/xdebug.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Failed loading /usr/lib/php5/20090626+lfs/xdebug.so:  /usr/lib/php5/20090626+lfs/xdebug.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Failed loading /usr/lib/php5/20090626+lfs/xdebug.so:  /usr/lib/php5/20090626+lfs/xdebug.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Failed loading /usr/lib/php5/20090626+lfs/xdebug.so:  /usr/lib/php5/20090626+lfs/xdebug.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Failed loading /usr/lib/php5/20090626+lfs/xdebug.so:  /usr/lib/php5/20090626+lfs/xdebug.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Failed loading /usr/lib/php5/20090626+lfs/xdebug.so:  /usr/lib/php5/20090626+lfs/xdebug.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
[Mon Jul 29 15:13:17 2013] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down
Failed loading /usr/lib/php5/20090626+lfs/xdebug.so:  /usr/lib/php5/20090626+lfs/xdebug.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
[Mon Jul 29 15:13:18 2013] [notice] Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu) PHP/5.3.10-1ubuntu3.7 with Suhosin-Patch configured -- resuming normal operations
[Mon Jul 29 15:13:48 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] (2)No such file or directory: Could not open password file: /path/to/passwords/.htpasswd
[Mon Jul 29 15:13:48 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] File does not exist: /home/hamed/public_html/favicon.ico
[Mon Jul 29 15:13:48 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] File does not exist: /home/hamed/public_html/favicon.ico
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The error `Internal Server Error` could mean more or less anything on the server side. Judging from your link you use Apache2 as a web server. Check the log files in the `/var/log/apache2/` directory, especially the `/var/log/apache2/error.log` for additional information.

Just from experience I would say that *apache* has wrong permissions on the *PHPMyAdmin* folder. Check that the `apache user` has reading permission in the `/usr/share/phpmyadmin/` folder.

Also keep in mind that you need to restart the apache web server after changing its configuration by running `service apache2 restart` or `sudo service apache2 restart`.

---

### Edit:

You did not change the path to the `.htpasswd` file in your configuration, which is why this error appears in your log files:

```
 Could not open password file: /path/to/passwords/.htpasswd
```

Read through the guide you used again very carefully and change the paths according to your needs.

I would recommend you move that `.htpasswd` file into the same directory as the `.htaccess`. In your terminal type

```
sudo mv ~/phpmyadmin_password/.htpasswd /usr/share/phpmyadmin/.htaccess
```

After that update your `/usr/share/phpmyadmin/.htaccess` file to look like this:

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Restricted Files"
AuthUserFile /usr/share/phpmyadmin/.htpasswd
Require valid-user
```

Also check file ownership and permissions of both files. The apache user should be able to read both these files.

Comment: First post edited.

Comment: I have created this path manually in `~/phpmyadmin_password/.htpasswd` how to change the path to that ?

Comment: check my answer again.